# How to improve session objects access in Rails 2.3.5. ActiveRecord storage is getting slower

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, activerecord

My web app is getting slower mainly due to Session objects access. I'm using the standard ActiveRecord storage in Rails 2.3.5. Could anyone give me some advice to make this faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delete old sessions after a reasonable expiration time. [Here's a task](http://blog.benpetro.com/2008/04/delete-old-sessions-in-rails.html) you can run via cron to do so. Note that it deletes sessions after an hour, customize to your liking.

Comment: I've changed the sentence by `ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.destroy_all(["updated_at<?", 1.hour.ago"])` and now it's working fine